# Не открываются внутренние страницы сайта и английская версия в IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Есть сайт https://playvr.ru/

Если попробовать открыть его в IE11 - то работает только главная страница, при переходе на внутренние страницы - перенаправляет обратно на главную и показывает такое сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-то сталкивался с таким, у кого какие идеи есть?

Кроме jQuery на фронте никаких особых библиотек не использую (хотя если бы ошибка была в JS - он бы в консоли показал это).

Еще неделю назад все работало отлично,
во всех остальных браузерах - так же все хорошо.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/cbJLyFIeoyzjxA помоему таки проблемы там есть и их много =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а как мне посмотреть это окно?

Comment: да вот в чем прикол, оно все работает, если переходить по ссылке в новой вкладке (нажатием на "колесо" мышки), даже в консоле практически никаких ошибок, только предупреждения. а еще переход нормально работает без этой фигни раз через раз

Comment: У Вас где-то ошибка в JS который отвечает за пеход между страницами или который патчит историю. Добавьте кусок который за это отвечает, возможно смогу помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Ты как-то криво перенаправляешь
[image: Не верное направление]
Тут вопрос, почему оно в Chrome правильно работает. Ещё посмотри на свой .htaccess Возможно там что-то захарткожено.

Comment: Спасибо за указание на ошибку, это возникло из-за смены схемы генерации url, но это не является ошибкой, описанной в вопросе

Comment: Ещё у IE есть что-то на подобие безопасного режима, его не надо включать.(Он там и анимацию и верстку может портить) Возможно это он всё ломает. Попробуй, сбросить кэш браузера, или посмотреть как сайт будет вести себя с чужого IE11. Ещё можно глянуть всё ли хорошо в Edge браузере (Windows 10) Это не очень похоже на фронтальную проблему

Answer (score 1):

То что IE не выдает ошибок в консоли не значит, что в нем нет проблем!

То что "съедают и сглаживают" современные браузеры, более старые и IE не воспринимают!

- Проверьте ваш сайт на валидацию:

  [validator.w3.org/.../playvr.ru](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fplayvr.ru%2F) - Там уйма грубейших ошибок (`div` перед `body`, не правильное использование ссылок и `href`, ...)!
- Еще один [тестировщик сео](https://sitechecker.pro/ru/seo-report/https://playvr.ru/), но отображает все возможные проблемы сайта. Он вот показывает ошибки по пунтку *Уязвимость URL* и предупреждения по внутренним страницам (ошибки опять же со ссылкми).
- Плюс тестировщик оптимизации сайта - [gtmetrix.com/.../playvr.ru](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/playvr.ru/Omeo7nD3) , который указывает на ошибки с подробным описанием как решить.

**Вывод:** Исправьте ошибки на сайте, оптимизируйте его, а потом задавайте такие вопросы, если они еще останутся)